# How does one become ranked by ITTF?

Tags: table-tennis, ranking, ittf

I was playing table tennis and met someone who was ranked 250 worldwide by International Table Tennis Federation (ITTF). Unfortunately, I did not have the chance to ask him how he went about doing this.

How does one get ranked by ITTF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Players get ranked based on their performance in tournaments. Per the [ITTF ranking page](https://www.ittf.com/rankings/), the ranking system as of 2017 ([full details here](https://d3mjm6zw6cr45s.cloudfront.net/2016/07/2017-WR-Basic-Principles.pdf)) incorporates:

- Wins and losses against ranked players
- Adjustment due to relative strength of opponent
- Weighting for different events
- Bonus points

There are also multiple tiers of competition:

- Men
- Women
- U21 (Men and Women)
- U18 (Boys and Girls)
- U15 (Boys and Girls)
- Doubles
- Teams

In this [ITTF news release](https://www.ittf.com/2017/11/07/ittf-implement-new-world-ranking-system-2018/), the ranking system will be revised, effective January 1, 2018. Changes include:

> 1. The new ranking is based on the final positions reached at the tournaments only (regardless the relative strength of the opponent
>      player).
> 2. Only bonus points are awarded (no rating points are given), which are valid for 12 months, except the World Championships.
> 3. NO loss of points in case of losing a match.
> 4. Ranking Points are fixed according to the point tables using different weightings for different types of events.
> 5. Only the best 8 results are considered on a yearly basis (with one continental event included).
> 6. Separated ranking lists for each age category (Senior, U-21, Junior, Cadet), taking into consideration only results in the
>      respective category.
> 7. Special seeding in case of injury and pregnancy